# Garage Wall Question- Insulation and vapour barrier?

Tags: insulation, walls, garage, vapor-barrier

We live in Vancouver, BC, Canada. We are redoing the wall that separates our house from the garage. The wall is built with 2 by 6's and has been insulated with Roxul R20 thermal batt insulation. On the house side of the wall (inside) we have the vapour barrier. What should we be putting on the outside (garage side) of the wall? Do we put that black tar paper as if it is a true exterior wall and then put 5/8" drywall? Or vapour barrier then drywall? Or just drywall?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure that do you want to achieve?